# Json format issue with flot chart in asp.net mvc application

Tags: json, charts, format, flot

I am working on a flot chart and I am unable to covert json string to required flot graph format. Below is what I tried.

My Json

```
        Data: [
                  { "Day": 8, "Visits": 145 },
                  { "Day": 7, "Visits": 26 }
              ];
```

Format I am trying to achieve: `[[0, 12], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]];`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = [{ "Day": 8, "Visits": 145 }, { "Day": 7, "Visits": 26 }];
        var dailyHits = [];
        $.each(data, function (_index, _item) {
            var c = [_item["Day"], _item["Visits"]];
            dailyHits.push(c);
        });

        //var dailyHits1= [[0, 12], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]];
        var chartData = [dailyHits];
        console.log(chartData);
        $.plot($("#chartHits"), chartData);
    });
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Do you get any javascript errors on the console?

Comment: no errros in console. I finally tried alternate way and it worked 
var dailyHits = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    var temp = [item["Day"], item["Visits"]];
                    dailyHits.push(temp);
                });
                dailyHits.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                var chartData = [dailyHits];
                $.plot($("#chartHits"), chartData);

Answer (score 1):

Hey i have same problem and i think problem is that you get data in string format, but array should be with Integers